# A flag or comment to show a record has been updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of employees. I want to display a comment or flag next to the employee name that the record has been updated/audited everytime someone does that.

How can I implement that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your record probably has an `updated_on` field. In your "audit" code call `record.save`, even if the record was not changed. This should update the `updated_on` field. (If it doesn't, change the record yourself with `record.updated_on = Time.now`.)

Then in your view html.erb file, add `<%= record.updated_on > 2.days.ago ? '*' : '' %>`, to put a star next to records recently changed or audited.

Comment: Thank you @Phlip for your reply. Does it mean I should add an `updated_on` field to the employees table?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [touch](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Timestamp/touch).